# Как передавать по сети структуры MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, c, сеть

Второй час вожусь, не могу понять как отправить структуру MYSQL_RES

Сервер:

```
MYSQL_RES *result;
mysql_query(conn,"запрос");
result=mysql_store_result(conn);
send(sock,result,sizeof(*result),0);
```

Клиент:

```
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_RES res;
recv(sock,&res,sizeof(res),0);
row=mysql_fetch_row(&res);
//|                      |
//V                      V
printf("row:%s\n",row[0]); //Здесь выводится ошибка сегментирования
```

На ошибки проверяю - их нет, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: `sizeof(result)` - размер указателя, думаю вам другое надо

Comment: Никак, структуры не предназначены для передачи по сети. Преобразовывайте нужные вам данные в строку (точнее в массив байт) и передавайте уже его

Comment: @andreymal почему в строку? В массив байт

Comment: Ну я на С не программирую конечно, но судя по всему вы хотите передать весь объект с результатом запроса, а по всей видимости ещё и с всеми методами через сеть, хотя сам этот объект вполне возможно не расчитан на такое использование и может использовать для своей работы какие-то глобальные данные из окружения... Так с объектами обращаются в java и то эти объекты предварительно разрабатываются с учетом их передачи в сериализованном виде по сети.

Comment: @dIm0n, ой, `sizeof(*result)` должно быть

Comment: Объект типа MYSQL_RES наверняка не содержит самих данных, а только некоторые данные на основе которых потом выполняется fetch. А fetch идет от вашего приложения к mysql по уже открытому соединению. А открытое соединение передать по сети физически невозможно. Так что единственный путь - выполнить fetch всех данных и их уже отправлять, причем в своей собственной структуре, про которую вы точно знаете что и в каком виде в ней содержится. И разумеется в ней не должно быть указателей, а только данные (с разделителями или фиксированной длины)

Answer (score 0):

Два замечания к Вашему коду.

Первое:

Лучше написать вот так:

```
send(sock,result,sizeof(MYSQL_RES),0);
```

По крайней мере, я понимаю однозначно, что здесь получится.

Второе - принципиальное.

Предположим, что "на том конце" Вы получили структуру *MYSQL_RES*. Правильно даже получили. И что? Разве эта структура содержит данные, полученные с SQL сервера? Нет.  Она содержит ссылку на *struct MYSQL_DATA *     data* И зачем вам эта ссылка ?! Она указывает на область памяти того компьютера, который выполнил *send()*. Как вы из памяти компьютера выполнившего *recv()* получите доступ к этой памяти ?! Никак...

Поэтому, выход тут только один: доставать с сервера **данные** а не их описатели и передавать конкретно **данные**.